# Variable - has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I've defined some variables in the same scope:

```
<xsl:variable name="disc" select="fn:number(a)"/>
<xsl:variable name="pvTotal" select="fn:number(b)"/>
<xsl:variable name="taxTotal" select="fn:number(c)"/>
```

And then I defined another variable in the same scope:

```
<xsl:variable name="pvUnitario" select="$pvTotal+$taxTotal-$disc"/>
```

But I get this error:

> XPST0008: Variable taxTotal- has not been declared (or its declaration is not in scope)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hyphen is a valid character in XML names (and therefore in variable names) so you should always surround a minus sign with spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:variable name="pvUnitario" select="$pvTotal+$taxTotal-$disc"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:variable name="pvUnitario" select="$pvTotal + $taxTotal - $disc"/>
```

so that `taxTotal` is referenced rather than `taxTotal-`.